# how to nest a kendo-window in kendo-treeview?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to nest a window in a treeview.  I want it so that when a user selects a particular node it will open a kendo window.  Has anyone done this?  I'm not seeing much on the demos that demonstrate something similar.

I'm using the mvc wrappers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Onclick event of your tree node

call this

```
$("tree node").click(function(){
 KendoDialog("Window TItle", "Content in the window", 700, 350);
});

function KendoDialog(windowTitle, message, windowWidth, windowHeight) {
    var WindowElement = $("#kwDialog").data("kendoWindow");
    WindowElement.setOptions({
        width: windowWidth,
        height: windowHeight,
        title: windowTitle
    });
    WindowElement.content("<b>" + message + "</b>");
    WindowElement.center().open();
}
```

put this some where in your layout

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
            .Name("kwDialog")
            .Title("Alert!")
            .Modal(true)
            .Visible(false)
           )
```